# Jquery ajaxStop

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there an obvious reason from the code below why this wouldn't work?

When i run, the "ajaxBusy" div never hides, and the "content" div never changes it's visibility settings. So i'm inclined to believe that .ajaxStop is never happening. I tried deleting all other javascript functions, but that didn't change anything.

In the head of an HTML document, I have:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
        $("#content").css('visibility','hidden');
        $('#ajaxBusy').ajaxStop(function(){ 
        alert('it ran!');
          $('#ajaxBusy').hide(); 
          $("#content").css('visibility','visible');
        });
    }); 
</script> --> 
<script src="sliding.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

where "ajaxBusy" contains a loading GI. It is the commented code this is not running properly.

Comment: Where are the ajax handlers? the stop will never run if there is no ajax

Comment: can you also post relevant html part? aside from using visibility which is not the best option, the ajaxBusy part should work.

Comment: I didnt use .hide() because when I tried to do the corresponding .show(), it would break the div.

Comment: what would be relevant outside the code I gave in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you bind .ajaxStop before calling your ajax request. I don't see any ajax in your code, I'm assuming that's not the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

hide() sets element css property `display:none` check in Firebug to confirm. visibility: visible will do nothing as the display and visibility properties hide a div in different ways. visibility hides to div but leaves it in the DOM, i.e. whereever the div is will show up empty. display:none displays the DOM as if the div was never there.

Comment: What I was getting at was, is display:none of #content by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    $('#ajaxBusy').ajaxStop(function(){ 
      $(this).hide(); 
      $("#content").show();
    });
```

As that's how it's used on the jquery api docs. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/. Use `.show();` and `.hide();` instead of setting the visibility css attribute.

Also, I would just drop an `alert('it ran!');` inside the callback to get quick feedback in your browser as to whether it's being called or not.

Comment: Ok. When is the ajax request in question being called? Is it possible that the ajax request is being fired before ajaxStop is called?

Comment: Is that what is supposed to happen? that all ajax requests fire before ajaxStop is called?  once all the ajax has run, then ajaxStop is called, right?

Comment: You want call ajaxStop with a callback as it's argument _before_ you make the ajax request. The completion of the ajax request then triggers the callback you passed into ajaxStop.

Comment: so, i added some more detail to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {

            alert('it ran!');
          $('#ajaxBusy').hide(); 
          $("#content").show();
        });
```

Your  `$('#ajaxBusy').ajaxStop(function(){})` probably did not capture the event of ajax call stops